# Extracting text from a dynamic pdf

Tags: python, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, data-analysis, vision

I have a react application in which the user submits a form. The form consists of a file upload
section where the user shall upload a pdf file. The file would consist of the travel details of the user including destination/start-date/end-date. I am supposed to read the pdf and get these details into the cosole.log.    How do I do this??

I thought of using vision API but since the files will be different for diff.users how do I make sure I am reading the correct file?

[sample pdf type](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/da406261-7335-4cdd-9bd2-768d42a1d02d/tui_com-robinson_noonu.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20220624%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220624T101943Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=7f4b623c33178d482c866e3660ca92f941b2313986e849fda938868e732bf30c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22tui_com-robinson_noonu.pdf%22&x-id=GetObject)

Comment: Can you add examples of the PDF files? Is there any consistency? for example: the layout of the travel details input field? A bounding box around it? The same text?

Comment: @user_cr I have added the file link

Comment: Wrong pdf? I don't see any field for travel details for the user. (and it's better to embed an image, in case this pdf is unavailable in the future)

Comment: there's details at the top section.

Comment: check below the name : Robinsson Nonnu , the details are there which includes destination as well.

Comment: Okee, I looked over it. you are looking to identify that text. so look for similarities between the pdfs. Is it always at the top under the line? Then it's easy, just extract the first 2 lines of text using OCR. If you want specific help, please provide use the code that you already tried, and a better description about your problem. it really vague now.

Comment: @user_cr I know how to extract the text, but since multiple users would be using the website they will upload different pdfs and I want to make sure Im reading the correct file . so how will I get the reference of the file by uploading to google cloud from my node.js server.

Comment: Please update your question! It is really not clear what your problem is. To answer to your comment: link the pdf filename with the booking code (top right), document id (bottom right: MLE11011-T01_MLE_11_011_0036_I_K8PK)